# Eclipse RCP run application

Tags: eclipse, rcp

I have a custom editor and implemented my own language similar to Java.
I have implemented my custom runner and want to run the application via the shortcut CTRL+F11. Which command is executed when running via shortcut?

[image]

Comment: I have already implemented a run configuration for this, but I cant run it via shortcut CTRL+F11. Do you have the link for the documentation of this part.

Comment: What does  "General > Keys" in the Preferences say for that binding? I'm using macOS which has different bindings.

Comment: see picture above.

Comment: That is called "Run Last Launched" now and has command id `org.eclipse.debug.ui.commands.RunLast`. It should not need to be changed.

Comment: yes thank you, this was it